# Question on uniform convergence of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

There is a theorem that $\to$

If $\{f_n\} \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $E$ and $c$ is a limit point of $E$ such that $\lim_{x \to c} f_n(x)=A_n$, for every $n$, then $\{A_n\}$ converges and $\lim_{n\to \infty} A_n=\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$.

My question is why uniform convergence is needed? I think pointwise convergence is enough for the theorem to work. Is there any counterexample? I tried with an example of a series of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}, x\in (0,\infty)$, which is not uniformly convergent but it is pointwise convergent to zero (i.e., the zero function). In this example, the above theorem works though it is not uniformly convergent. Or maybe I am doing something wrong. If it is possible, can anyone help me find a limit point in this example which doesn't work?

This is what I did--

$A_n= \frac{nc}{1+n^2c^2}$ where $c$ is a limiting point. And, clearly, $\lim_{n\to \infty} A_n=0$ for $c>0$. For $c=0$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}A_n$ is obviously $0$. Also, $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=0$ as $f(x)=0$. So, both are equal.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider the classic $x^n$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt So, this example works for the limiting point $1$. Is it correct?

Comment: Mhm, the point which causes the pointwise convergence.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Sorry, I didn't understand your point. Here, for the limit point $1$, $A_n=1$. So, $\lim_{n\to \infty} A_n=1$. Also, $x^n$ pointwise converges to $0$ on the interval $(0,1)$. So, $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=0$, which I think gives a contradiction.

Comment: Okay... you showed it gives a contradiction, so what more do you want/what part are you unsure of?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Okay, I thought you said, I got it wrong. Just a misunderstanding. Thanks for your help.